# Objective-C - What's techniques/objects are being used

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

On my iPhone, when I go into the Settings app, I see "Airplane Mode", "Wi-Fi", "Notifications", etc. and I'm able to scroll through pages and pages of settings.

I'm new to objective-c and I'm trying to duplicate the functionality in my own app, but I don't know enough about the objects and techniques to know what to ask or what to look for. :)

With that in mind, can someone please explain what's going on with the settings app? What is this using? Is it a UITableView that allows me to scroll down the page? What control is being used to store the text "Airplane" mode? What is happening when I click on the ">" and see a new page?

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While nobody outside Apple can be 100% sure how they implement their apps, some reasonable guesses would be:

- The main screen is a grouped UITableView. Each entry is a single cell.
- The text and images in the cells are built using properties of UITableViewCell (e.g. the `textLabel` UILabel for the text "General"). Some of the more advanced items use custom cell views.
- Each category view is another UIViewController, pushed onto the `viewControllers` stack of a UINavigationController.
- The on/off switches are UISliders.

Answer (score 1):

It is a TableView

- [Table View programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/)
- [samplecode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html)

These docs cover all you need